# Scala type inference not working with generic case class and lambda

Tags: scala, generics, types, lambda

I am trying to apply a function: A => B to a Result[A] to get a Result[B] and am getting a weird type error.

```
 found   : Product with Serializable with this.Result[_ <: B]
 required: this.Result[B]
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. It looks like scala is trying to convert the output of the function to be a string (serializable) because it can't find a conversion between Success/Failure and Result?

The simplified code is below. I tried attaching explicit type information and the code would not compile. Any help would be appreciated!

```
sealed trait Result[A]{ 
    def map[B](f: A => B) = this match{
        case Success((a, rest)) => Success((f(a), rest))
        case Failure(m) => Failure(m)
    }
}
case class Success[A](result: (A, List[Char])) extends Result[A]
case class Failure[A](message: String) extends Result[A]

object Utils{
    def map[A,B](r: Result[A], f: A => B):Result[B] = {
        r.map(f)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the original issue: you don't specify return type of `Result.map`, so Scala has to infer it. To do so, it looks at both branches. The return type of the first one is `Success[B]`. The return type of the second is `Failure[Nothing]`, because Scala has no reason to assume you mean `Failure[B](m)` there!

So now it has to find the type which both `Success[B]` and `Failure[Nothing]` fit (their *least upper bound*). Well, they both extend `Product` and `Serializable` (because they are case classes). They also both extend `Result`, but with different type parameters. The least upper bound of `Nothing` and `B` is `B`, so they both extend `Result[_ <: B]`. And that's the type you end up for `map`: `Product with Serializable with Result[_ <: B]`.

Note that by applying Andy Hayden's answer, you will get `Product with Serializable with Result[B]` instead, *not* `Result[B]` which is probably what you want. To do that, either specify the return type explicitly (which works even without covariance, hopefully you can now see why), or make `Result` extend `Product with Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov), you should specify the return type of Result's map (otherwise the Failure type is ambiguous, although you can specify the Failure type instead `Failure[B]`):

```scala
sealed trait Result[A]{ 
    // specify the return type Result[B]
    def map[B](f: A => B): Result[B] = this match{
        case Success((a, rest)) => Success((f(a), rest))
        case Failure(m) => Failure(m)  // alternatively use Failure[B](m) here
    }
}
case class Success[A](result: (A, List[Char])) extends Result[A]
case class Failure[A](message: String) extends Result[A]

object Utils{
    def map[A,B](r: Result[A], f: A => B):Result[B] = {
        r.map(f)
    }
}
```

This will give a Failure the correct type:

```
scala> val f = Failure[Int]("oops")
Failure("oops"): Failure[Int]

scala> Utils.map(f, {i: Int => 4})
Failure("oops"): Result[Int]
```

vs (with the covariant solution below):

```
scala> Utils.map(f, {i: Int => 4})
Failure(oops): Product with Serializable with Result[_37] forSome { type _37 <: Int }
```

which is not what you want!

---

Originally I suggested that you make your types covariant (the `+A`):

```
sealed trait Result[+A]{ 
    def map[B](f: A => B) = this match{
        case Success((a, rest)) => Success((f(a), rest))
        case Failure(m) => Failure(m)
    }
}
case class Success[A](result: (A, List[Char])) extends Result[A]
case class Failure[A](message: String) extends Result[A]

object Utils{
    def map[A,B](r: Result[A], f: A => B):Result[B] = {
        r.map(f)
    }
}
```

See [this great blogpost](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/the-scala-type-system-parameterized-types-and-variances-part-2/#condensed) for more discussion.

To quote part of the post:

> Subtype Relationships
>   Assume that class Orange extends Fruit holds.
>   If class `Box[A]` is declared, then `A` can be prefixed with `+` or `-`.
>
> A without annotation is invariant, i.e.:
>   `Box[Orange]` has no inheritance relationship to `Box[Fruit]`.
>
> +A is covariant, i.e.:
>   `Box[Orange]` is a subtype of `Box[Fruit]`.
>   `var f: Box[Fruit] = new Box[Orange]()` is allowed.
>
> -A is contravariant, i.e.:
>   `Box[Fruit]` is a subtype of `Box[Orange]`.
>   `var f: Box[Orange] = new Box[Fruit]()` is allowed.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with covariance and contravariance. I'm newer to scala and it is something I'm still not clear on. Thanks a bunch, the blog post was super helpful.

Comment: "Essentially this tells scala that Success[B] and Failure[B] are subtypes of Result[B]. " This is completely wrong, `Success[A](...) extends Result[A]` does _that_. You should also make both `Success` and `Failure` covariant as well.